# Vancouver style referencing in Beamer

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, citing, natbib

This is my first time posting here, sorry for any mistakes in formatting I may have made.

I need to create a Beamer document where I reference my sources (preferably) in the Vancouver style.

So far, I have used:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[numbers,round,comma]{natbib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{References}
\bibliography{references}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This produces a bibliography that looks like this (a sample):[image]

It does not seem to matter whether or what `\bibliographystyle` I use as the output is always the same.

Is there a way to reference in a Beamer document using the Vancouver style?

Comment: If I add `\bibliographystyle{vancouver}` to your document, it produces the bibliography correctly, i.e. the same style as with `article` class. Did you delete your `.aux` files an recompile/run `bibtex` when you changes styles?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Alan Munn's comment I was able to work out what had been the issue. Like he had guessed, the problem lied in the fact that I was not switching between bibliography styles correctly.

The referencing and bibliography started coming together after I changed the citation style, then ran PdfLaTeX, then ran BibTeX, and then ran PdfLaTeX (twice).

Thank you for your help!